# Command in powershell to enter free text to a text file

Tags: powershell, textbox, powershell-2.0

I've done a bit of searching, but cant seem to find anything, so its making me question if something like this actually exists.

But is there a command in powershell that allows free text to be entered in the powershell window or even a pop up box which will then ultimately add the text to a text file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Read-Host | out-file yourfile.txt -append
```

if you want to work with the input before saving it to a file you could do something like this:

```
$text = Read-Host
#do stuff
$text | out-file yourfile.txt -append
```